# Sending from external system to Kafka without duplicates in a transaction

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a requirement to send data from an external system to a Kafka topic with exactly once semantics.
The source has an offset, we can consume messages from a given offset.

Looking at Kafka documentation, I see there are 2 ways to do this.

1. Kafka Source Connector
2. Use plain Kafka producer with transactions.

It looks like option 1 doesn't support exactly once semantics now, [Kafka jira  6080](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6080) is unresolved. Also I would like to understand how we can do this directly with the producer apis.
For option 2, the (consume, transform, produce) loop  in all the documents show committing offsets of consumers using AddOffsetsToTxn. What is the recommended strategy if the source is not a Kafka topic? Looks like writing the source offset in a different topic as part of the transaction and using it during recovery would work. Is this the recommended way?